# Condition for a line to be tangent of a parabola

Tags: derivatives

I just read that the line `y = kx + n` will be tangent line of a parabola `y^2 = 2px` if derivatives of both of them are the same. Now, derivative of the line is equal to the slope of that line and the derivative of the parabola will be equal to the slope of the tangent line in point `A(x, y)` that belongs to parabola. My questions are:

a) If those two derivatives are the same, is there a possibility that the line `y = kx + n` is only parallel with the potential tangent line (because `k1 = k2` is condition for the lines to be parallel) ?

b) If a is correct, wouldn't the proper condition be that `y = kx + n` and `y^2 = 2px` have one point in common? In that case, I would solve the system of these two equasions, get the quadratic equasion and solve just the `b^2 - 4ac = 0` part (so that the quadratic equasion would have only one solution, thus only one common point for the line and parabola)?

I hope I made myself clear and I apologize for my poor English skills (kinda hard to deal with all the technical terms) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your assumptions are correct.You or the book should better say, " At tangent point derivatives should be equal". In fact, the condition is the same for any two curves. Your English is quite good.

As you say by eliminating x you get a quadratic in y, setting $ b^2- 4 a c = 0 $ it is possible to get y and x for point of tangency.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

""I just read that the line y = kx + n will be tangent line of a parabola y^2 = 2px if derivatives of both of them are the same""

It isn't true.  n could be any number but only one would allow the tangents to be at the same point.